# React instance variable undefined

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a base component where i want to have an instance level variable that is updated by subclasses. The only way i can get this work is to add it to state which i don't want to do due to the fact that the value of this variable is NOT related to the UI so i don't want to trigger a re-render.

So take following component:

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.params = [];
  }

  addParam(name) {
    this.params.push(name);
  }

  getUrl() {//this.params is always undefined
    return format("{0}?", this.constructor.name, this.params.join("&");
  }
}
```

So this.params is always undefined which makes sense since it is not part of state. This variable is related to the url and not the UI so when the value is updated i don't want to have to trigger a re-render by updating the state.

Not sure what the best approach here is?

Options i know of:

1) Add to state which will trigger re-render

2) Call forceUpdate() which will also trigger re-render

I don't like either of these options so i am hoping someone knows the correct way to do what i am trying to do.

Comment: You're setting `this.params` equal to an array, and also treating it as such in the `getUrl()` method. However, in the `addParam()` method, it looks more like an object, unless `name` is a number? This may not be causing your issue right now though. It would depend on how `getUrl()` is called and if `addParam()` is called first.

Comment: @technicallynick yes you are correct but not the issue. I will update post to not confuse people

Comment: You don't want to re-render because the url doesn't affect the UI, but re-rendering is probably your best choice and shouldn't cause a performance issue because the dom won't actually change. More information here https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary

Comment: @Burgan yes i am aware that dom wont actually change which is good. I was just wondering if there was an alternative?

Comment: You could store the url in state, but implement shouldComponentUpdate to avoid rerenders https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate